# Selector with string space and /; $(" /") throws uncaught error in jquery

Tags: jquery

We have a condition to get DOM hierarchy selector but when the string contains anything with space and slash like $('aaa /aaa') in jquery and this was throwing error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /

Comment: Spaces are fine, but the selector shouldn't contain a slash. Why do you think it should? What are you trying to target that contains a slash? `'aaa /aaa'` is not a valid DOM element.

Comment: Why would you have a `/` in your selector? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to space. It's about `/`. As we can see in [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), to use any of the **meta-characters** (such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector

```
$("#foo\\.bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the errors is because, you must escape any forward slash / with a double backward slash \\

## Example

```
$("aaa \\/aaa")
```